# Select a Dictionary<T1, T2> with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have used the "select" keyword and extension method to return an `IEnumerable<T>` with LINQ, but I have a need to return a generic `Dictionary<T1, T2>` and can't figure it out.  The example I learned this from used something in a form similar to the following:

```
IEnumerable<T> coll = from x in y 
    select new SomeClass{ prop1 = value1, prop2 = value2 };
```

I've also done the same thing with extension methods.  I assumed that since the items in a  `Dictionary<T1, T2>` can be iterated as `KeyValuePair<T1, T2>` that I could just replace "SomeClass" in the above example with "`new KeyValuePair<T1, T2> { ...`", but that didn't work (Key and Value were marked as readonly, so I could not compile this code).

Is this possible, or do I need to do this in multiple steps?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698418/8479

Answer (score 354, accepted):

The extensions methods also provide a [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) extension.  It is fairly simple to use, the general usage is passing a lambda selector for the key and getting the object as the value, but you can pass a lambda selector for both key and value.

```
class SomeObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

SomeObject[] objects = new SomeObject[]
{
    new SomeObject { ID = 1, Name = "Hello" },
    new SomeObject { ID = 2, Name = "World" }
};

Dictionary<int, string> objectDictionary = 
    objects.ToDictionary(
        o => o.ID, 
        o => o.Name);
```

Then `objectDictionary[1]` Would contain the value "Hello"

Answer (score 71):

A more explicit option is to project collection to an IEnumerable of `KeyValuePair` and then convert it to a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = objects
    .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Id, x.Name))
    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove   .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value); and replace new KeyValuePair with new Dictionary ?

Comment: @AmirHajiha - no, because the `new KeyValuePair...` part is called _for each item_. It needs to be code that returns whatever the items are (e.g. KeyValuePair), not the whole collection (e.g. Dictionary). Once you've created all the items you have an `IEnumerable` and you can convert that into a dictionary.

Comment: @Antoine - there's no need to use `KeyValuePair` here, rather an anonymous type works just as well and somewhat more concise, e.g. `objects.Select(x=> new { x.Id, x.Name }).ToDictionary(x=>x.Id, x=>x.Name)`

Answer (score 46):

```
var dictionary = (from x in y 
                  select new SomeClass
                  {
                      prop1 = value1,
                      prop2 = value2
                  }
                  ).ToDictionary(item => item.prop1);
```

That's assuming that `SomeClass.prop1` is the desired `Key` for the dictionary.

Comment: `.ToDictionary(item => item.prop1, item => item.prop2);` to explicity set the value too.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the solution of hross because his version puts alle items of an array into one dictionary element.

I wanted to have each array item in its own dictionary item. This has two advantages:

- It is easier to work with if you have arrays which contain objects or other array instead of values.
- The dictionary key is compatible with the JSON path of Json.Net.

The key to this solution is the fact that JToken knows its path (JToken.Path) so it is not necessary to assemble it for yourself. This makes the new solution surprisingly simple.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string?>? GetJsonDictionary(JToken? token)
{
    if (token == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string?>();
    ParseJToken(token, dict);
    return dict;
}

private static void ParseJToken(JToken token, Dictionary<string, string?> nodes)
{
    if (token.HasValues)
    {
        // The node has children.
        foreach (JToken child in token.Children())
        {
            ParseJToken(child, nodes);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The node is a leaf.
        nodes.Add(token.Path, token.ToString());
    }
}
```